# How to expose MySQL logs to screen from mysqld?

Tags: mysql

I'm running `mysqld` in command line in non-daemon mode, and want to see logs right here, instead of in files:

```
mysql --port=1234 --bind-address=localhost --datadir=./data
```

It works, but logs go to files. I want to see them right here. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that; can you tail -f the logfiles instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start mysqld with the --general-log option, which it would cause it to display log messages on screen:

```
mysql --port=1234 --bind-address=localhost --datadir=./data --general-log
```